# Plural form of macrame?

Tags: plural-forms

Is "macrames" a correct plural form of "macrame" in English? I am seeing "macrame" being used in various places, but if I want to give two items to my friend, am I giving them "two macrame" or "two macrames"?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**macramé**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/macrame) noun **[ U ]** 
​

> the art of joining pieces of string together in knots to form a
>   decorative pattern, or something made this way

The [U] stands for **uncountable**

> Uncountable or singular noun: **a noun that has no plural**.

So if you want to give your friend two items, I think that the correct way of saying it is: **two pieces of macramé**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also found the following definition: _Macramé is a form of textile produced using knotting (rather than weaving or knitting) techniques._

Wiktionary presents it as a countable and uncountable noun (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/macrame).

Comment: @WojtekZeglin Oxford Dictionary classifies it as a mass noun (uncountable) too. It depends on what reference you trust most.

Comment: @WojtekZeglin - It's not uncommon to find a word that's listed as `countable` in one dictionary, but `countable and uncountable` in another, especially when a random plural form is rarely used. (See, e.g., the entry for _equipment_ in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/equipment) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equipment).) As a footnote, research like what you wrote here belongs in your question, not in comments beneath the answers to your question.

Comment: **macrame** refers to the manner of creation like "knitting" or "tie-dye". *She showed him a piece of macrame her mother had done.*

Comment: Art forms per se are not typically pluralized.  We wouldn't say "She showed them her knittings" but "... her knitting" or "her pieces of knitting".